# Convergence of series comparison

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

To determine if this series converges i was thinking to compare it to the series of $\frac{1}{n}$, is that a good way to handle this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the integral test, as $$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{8}{n\sqrt{\ln n}} dn$$ doesn't look too bad to integrate with the right substitution.

Comment: so if i do u sub with u=ln n then the integral becomes the integral of 8/u, at that point i can do the integral test?